# How performant is it to use $parent in vue?

Tags: performance, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I don't really know how much impact it could have, but I currently have 7 sub-pages and I import them as components in my root "site administration" and need to pass data between them. To be more precise, each sub route allows the user to add, edit and delete certain items in the site administration section.

From what I know, I could just make those sections sub routes and use router-view to show them in the parent page. But then I'd have to add 4 methods in each sub-route. Currently I'm just accessing those functions through $parent.someFuntion(), because I made them generic for any item. However, there are about 8 parent accesses from each child right now (variables and methods).

My question now is: What is more perfomant? Having seperated sub routes with redundant code or accessing the parent's methods with the $parent keyword?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It's generally bad practice to access `$parent` or `$children`. When you need parent-to-child communication, you should be passing values from parent to child via a `prop` and `watch` for changes in the child component. For child-to-parent communication, you should `$emit` an event and any necessary data and capture them with the appropriate `v-on:event_name` handler. Otherwise, you end up tightly coupling your components together and reduce maintainability and reusability of your components. I recommend either following this guideline or instead using routes as both are far better solutions.

Comment: @B.Fleming but isn't the impact of emitting events for setting variables and calling parent functions much higher than doing it directly?

Comment: Even if the performance would be wors,e it would be so minimal you would barely notice it unless you are dealing with a ton of components. Still it would be advisable to not use tight-coupling. And if you using props and emit events all over the place to communicate it would be better to use Vuex. The moment this even becomes a performance issue is the moment you have done something extremely wrong.

Comment: As stated above, the performance impact should be negligible. If it isn't, then you need to seriously reconsider whether or not you're approaching the problem correctly. Additionally, application performance shouldn't be your only consideration; maintainability should be one of your biggest concerns. If your code isn't sufficiently maintainable, then you're going to run into some major headaches down the line when you have to change something. Tightly coupling your components could prove to be a very expensive long-term decision.

Comment: Alright... I'll try to use props and events. I just want to make things as generic as possible. It's really sad that vue doesn't have inheritance models like low level languages have it.. But I'll keep you advice in mind and try to avoid the tight coupling